# Spring Response Entity Return type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jhipster

i want to display the response body of a link taken from user. i am using JHipster

this is my code

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/url-checks",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<UrlCheck> postresult(@RequestBody UrlCheck urlCheck) throws URISyntaxException {

    UrlCheck result = urlCheckRepository.save(urlCheck);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new URI("/api/url-checks/") + result);
}
```

i am gettinng following error

> /web/rest/UrlCheckResource.java:[98,62] bad operand types for binary operator '+'
>     first type:  java.net.URI
>     second type: com.oai.domain.UrlCheck

what can i do ? i am struggeling with it for a while

the UrlCheck Class

```
    package com.oai.domain;


    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Objects;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "url_check")
    public class UrlCheck implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "oai_url")
    private String oai_url;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOai_url() {
        return oai_url;
    }

    ////
    public String posttOai_url() {
        return oai_url;
    }
    ////****////
    public UrlCheck oai_url(String oai_url) {
        this.oai_url = oai_url;
        return this;
    }

    public void setOai_url(String oai_url) {
        this.oai_url = oai_url;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        UrlCheck urlCheck = (UrlCheck) o;
        if(urlCheck.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, urlCheck.id);
    }

    @Override
     public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UrlCheck{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", oai_url='" + oai_url + "'" +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to add new URI("/api/url-checks/") ?

Comment: in order to connect the localhost api with the input link . i am not sure.  there was a generated code by jhipster. i am following that. i am new with Jhipster

Answer (score 1):

Your method actual return type is not compatible with the decalred return type which is `ResponseEntity<UrlCheck>`,

So simply change it to:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
```

Comment: i have tried this before. with this i am not getting the response from the page.

Comment: added in the section

Comment: What is the error you are getting if you change like in my answer above: return ResponseEntity.ok(result);

Comment: there was no error ... but its not doing what it suppose to do.